# WPF Sub-MenuItems don't show under top layer MenuItems

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, menuitem, submenu

I am trying to create a basic menu system in my WPF project. I have applied the attached style through `App.xaml`. When I click on a top-level menu item, it's sub-MenuItems are not shown.

I suspect that the ContentPresenter should have been refactored, but I can't find any content about the correct configuring.

What should I refactor to make this simple style work with sub-MenuItems?

The attached style in `App.xaml`:

```cs
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Menu}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#da4148"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#da4148"/>

                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                            <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Uid="Border_38" Margin="0,10,0,0" Padding="3">

                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                                  Grid.Column="1" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="#ffffff"/>
                                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" TargetName="Border" Value="#da4148"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

The Menu itself:

```cs
<DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
            <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <MenuItem Command="{Binding OpenHomePageCommand}">
                    <MenuItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/home.png" />
                            <ContentPresenter Content="Home" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </MenuItem.Header>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource File}" Height="40">
                    <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource SaveFile}" Command="{Binding SaveFileCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding FileDisplayerViewModel.DisplayedFile}" Height="30"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource Exit}" Command="{Binding CloseApplicationCommand}" Height="30"/>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource Settings}" Height="40">
                    <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource Watermark}" Command="{Binding ShowWatermarkWindowCommand}" Height="30"/>

                    <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource Language}" Height="30">
                        <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource English}" Command="{Binding SetEnglishLanguageCommand}" Height="30"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource Hungarian}" Command="{Binding SetHungarianLanguageCommand}" Height="30"/>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource ApplicationProperties}" Command="{Binding ShowApplicationPropertiesWindowCommand}" Height="30"/>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource Help}" Height="40">
                    <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource Help}" Height="30" Command="{Binding OpenHelpWebsiteCommand}"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource About}" Height="30" Command="{Binding AboutCommand}"/>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </DockPanel>
```

When I move the mouse over a MenuItem, the hover style works, but the sub-MenuItems are not shown:

[image: not shown sub-menuitems]

Answer (score 2):

The `Menu` is a tree structure that is entirely composed of `MenuItem` elements. It has a root node (header item)  and children (sub items). If the sub item is also a node (that can have children) than this node must be a header too. Header is also a `MenuItem` but differently templated. It has a `popup` that contains an item panel which displays the children.

Right now you are using an implicit `Style` that also overrides all header items and turn it into a normal child item that can hold children and can't expand (no popup). So you are basically missing a `Popup` that holds the submenu items. If you want to override the header template as well you have to add something similar to this:

```
<!-- TopLevelHeader -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey}"
                 TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
  <Border x:Name="Border">
    <Grid>
      <ContentPresenter Margin="6,3,6,3"
                        ContentSource="Header"
                        RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
      <Popup x:Name="Popup"
             Placement="Bottom"
             IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}"
             AllowsTransparency="True"
             Focusable="False"
             PopupAnimation="Fade">
        <Border x:Name="SubmenuBorder"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                BorderThickness="1"
                Background="{DynamicResource MenuPopupBrush}">
          <Border.BorderBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" />
          </Border.BorderBrush>
          <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True"
                        Style="{StaticResource MenuScrollViewer}">
            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                        KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
          </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
      </Popup>
    </Grid>
  </Border>
  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation"
             Value="true">
      <Setter TargetName="Popup"
              Property="PopupAnimation"
              Value="None" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted"
             Value="true">
      <Setter TargetName="Border"
              Property="BorderBrush"
              Value="Transparent" />
      <Setter Property="Background"
              TargetName="Border">
        <Setter.Value>
          <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                               EndPoint="0,1">
            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
              <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource ControlLightColor}" />
                <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource ControlMouseOverColor}"
                              Offset="1.0" />
              </GradientStopCollection>
            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
          </LinearGradientBrush>

        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger SourceName="Popup"
             Property="AllowsTransparency"
             Value="True">
      <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder"
              Property="CornerRadius"
              Value="0,0,4,4" />
      <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder"
              Property="Padding"
              Value="0,0,0,3" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
             Value="False">
      <Setter Property="Foreground">
        <Setter.Value>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundColor}" />
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Trigger>
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Alternatively you can make your `MenuItem` style explicit and apply it directly to the submenu items.

But the recommended way is to use the resource tempate keys that the `Menu` is using. Just define a `ControlTemplate and override the template resource key (e.g.:`TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey`or`SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey`)

Header item:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey}"
                 TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
</ControlTemplate>
```

You can find the full default templates at [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/menu-styles-and-templates#menu-and-menuitem-controltemplate-example). It shows how to override all four template resource keys. You can modify them to meet your requirements.

Each resource key maps to a [`MenuItemRole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.menuitemrole?view=netframework-4.8#fields) (e.g. `TopLevelHeader`). Use the resource key to describe the layout and the role to describe the behavior.